# Can't get post data from jQuery UI sortable (sent to the same file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, post

I have a little quiz written in php with questions of two types : single choice answer via radio buttons and multiple choice answers via checkboxes. The code run in a single file ("quiz.php") that handles the display of the questions as well as the treatment of the answers.

Everything was working smoothly until I had to add a third type for "sortable list" of answers --where people have to re-order a list of choices.

After some research, I've found what I think is the answer : the "sortable" interaction of jQuery UI. Simple, straightforward and easy to implement… even if I can't seem to make it work !

My problem is that if I know a little bit of PHP/MySql, I know very little of Javascript and certainly not know enough to write or debug it properly.

Here's the code, starting with all the php for the display of questions and the process of the answers :

```
// File quiz.php
<?php session_start();

// if the form has just been submitted, handle the answers
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Do something, on a case by case basis :
    switch ($_SESSION['questionType']) {
    case 1 : // for radio buttons
        // some code to process and save the answer to the database
    break ;
    case 2 : // for checkboxes
        // some code to process and save the answer to the database
    break ;
    case 3 : // for sortable lists
        // some code to process and save the answer to the database
    break ;
    }
  }
// Here, get the elements to show from the DB, including
// the question type for the switch below 
// questionType = 1 for single choice answer
// questionType = 2 for multiple choice answer
// questionType = 3 for sortable choice answer
?>
```

Next, the html to display the questions :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <title>Quiz</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href=./quiz.css">
   <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="./js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <?php // A bunch of code to echo the question ?>

    <form action="quiz.php" method="POST">
 <?php  // A switch to adapt the display to the type of questions :
    switch ($_SESSION['questionType']) {
        case 1 : // for single choice answer
            // A bunch of code to echo the possible choices w/ radio buttons
        break ;
        case 2 : // for multiple choice answer
            // A bunch of code to echo the possible choices w/ checkboxes
        break ;
        case 3 : // for sortable lists ?>
    <!-- the following would normaly be generated via php with info from the DB  -->
    <ul id="sort">
      <li id="choice_1">Item 1</li>
      <li id="choice_2">Item 2</li>
      <li id="choice_3">Item 3</li>
      <li id="choice_4">Item 4</li>
      <li id="choice_5">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
<?php   break ; ?>
<?php  } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and this is where it breaks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#sort").sortable({
      var newOrder = $(this).sortable('serialize'); 
      // the 'quiz.php' file called below is the one we're in
      $.post('quiz.php', {sort: newOrder };
    });
    $("#sort").disableSelection();
  });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What has me stumped is that not only is the result not sent to $_POST after the form has been submitted --so nothing happens-- but the 2 lines of code inside the $("#sort").sortable() function breaks the interaction behavior completely i.e the list isn't sortable AND the text can be selected.

Any hint, help ?

[EDIT] : Thanks to Jordan, I've got the sortable part runing but the data still isn't being sent.

The code in use now :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $('#sort-form').on('submit',function(event){
        // Prevent the form from being submitted normally
        event.preventDefault();
        var newOrder = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.post('quiz.php', {sort: newOrder };
    }); 
 </script>
```

doesn't result in anything, with the console in Chrome now saying that there is an "Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected end of input" juste before the closing  tag. 
I don't know if it's relevant or not but it has me thinking that
either I'm missing a typo somewhere or the function needs more arguments…

[EDIT 2] Replaced the "-" on the `<li>` id's with underscores (more compliant w/ jQuery UI guidelines)

Comment: Hey btw you're missing another `});` after that last one, that's why you're getting the unexpected end of input error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization and ajax call won't work in the sortable function because you're trying to define them as options on the sortable component itself. You should listen for when a button is pressed and then get your serialization and call the ajax function

So you could add an `id` to the form like

```
<form action="quiz.php" method="POST" id="sort-form">
```

And then listen in jQuery for when the form is trying to be submitted

```
$('#sort-form').on('submit',function(event){
    // Prevent the form from being submitted normally
    event.preventDefault();
    var newOrder = $('#sort').sortable('serialize', {
        key: 'sort'
    });
    $.post('quiz.php', newOrder);
});
```

And now when you're calling the sortable component just call it like this

```
$("#sort").sortable();
$("#sort").disableSelection();
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't wish to use Ajax to submit the form data you can try to set a hidden input to have the value set as the serialized sort data, something like this

```
$('#sort-form').on('submit',function(event){
    // Prevent the form from being submitted normally
    event.preventDefault();
    var newOrder = $('#sort').sortable('serialize', {
        key: 'sort'
    });
    $('.hidden-input-class').val(newOrder);
    // Submit the form like normal
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. Color me dumb, though, because I have no real idea of where to put the "listen on jQuery" part of your answer : in the same `$(function(){}` as the sortable component or elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes, the `$(function){}` part is the wrapper that all jQuery should go into. I would recommend that you read up on some jQuery basics as you're going along, it will help you understand what's happening and how to set up jQuery plugins and such

Comment: OK, I've read a bit about how and where to put things regarding jQuery, that part seems ok, now. The problem is that the datas still are't sent : `print_r($_POST)` returns an array with just  `[submit] => Submit`, nothing else.

Comment: I updated the answer, I looked up the proper API for the sortable function and updated it accordingly. I also have this jsbin that logs the serialized data so you can see what you should be seeing. https://jsbin.com/qozibov/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thxs again but still no dice… I've discovered a missing `});` at the end so the SyntaxError is now gone, but the only other effect --with either version of your code -- is that now the submit doesn't seems to fire at all : not only does the $_POST array is blank but the sortable list stay in the new order which leads me to believe that the page isn't reloaded.

Comment: OK, new element, w/ your updated code, the console is now giving me this : `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'serialize'`. Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure, check the jsbin link I added in the comment and compare to how you have it setup on your page, the example on jsbin works fine even if sortable is defined once before calling serialize.

Comment: Still at it. I now have the right output in the console : `choice[]=5&choice[]=2&choice=[]1&choice[]=4&choicei[]=3` but nothing on the post side, the page isn't reloaded by submitting the form. The rub seems to be in `$.post('quiz.php', newOrder);` although I don't see why.

Comment: Check the extra example I gave on how you might do this without ajax

Comment: OK, that one did the trick. Thanks again --and a lot-- for your help and patience. Have a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

well I removed it anyways as I should not have placed it here anyway. Should have thaught it over a bit more I guess. I believe it was relevant but maybe not clear at all. But anyho, to avoid further strange things from happing on my server I removed it so considder it never said. Good luck with it, hope you get your answer soon.

Comment: (??) I'm sorry but I think you must have answered the wrong question as I don't see the relevance of your input to the problem at hand (??)

Comment: Thanks anyway, but it was really a case of using a hammer to swat a fly, I'm afraid : your answer was WAY above my needs (and my level and pay grade, now that I think about it). Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: mm maybe I should have read it a bit better also. I saw serialize and a post method and I thought you had problems getting a object accross from the database with json object. I use a rest api based model so the approach is different I guess.